# Passing values from database to flip cards in JS React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am trying to pass my API value to the Flippy card to dynamically render image and the word displayed on flip.

I am struggling with something I thought would be easy: I have an API where I call back an image link and a word to populate the flip cards. I want to dynamically render my flip cards to the page using that data, but right now my image link and the word are hard coded and I don't know to pass my API call values to the component. API works and correctly returns links and words; hard coded flip card also works with no issues and functions as intended. I believe I have to implement props and pass it somehow to the const DefaultCardContents- thanks so much for taking a stab at it.

I tried implemeneting props but I am unsure how to pass them to the constant

THIS IS MY FLASHCARD COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Flippy, { FrontSide, BackSide } from './../lib';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import './style.css';
const FlippyStyle = {
width: '200px',
height: '200px',
textAlign: 'center',
color: '#FFF',
fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
fontSize: '30px',
justifyContent: 'center'
}

const DefaultCardContents = ({ children }) => (
<React.Fragment>
<FrontSide
style={{
backgroundColor: 'white',
display: 'flex',
alignItems: 'center',
flexDirection: 'column'
}}
>
<img
src="https://parent.guide/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Banana-baby-food-recipes.jpg"
style={{ maxWidth: '100%', maxHeight: '100%' }}
/>
<span
style={{
fontSize: '12px',
position: 'absolute',
bottom: '10px',
width: '100%'
}}>
{children}<br />
Hover over to show key word
</span>
</FrontSide>
<BackSide
style={{
backgroundColor: '#EB6864',
display: 'flex',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
flexDirection: 'column'
}}>
<h1>Banana</h1>
<span
style={{
fontSize: '12px',
position: 'absolute',
bottom: '10px',
width: '100%'
}}>
{children}<br />
<Button variant="success">Success</Button>
<Button variant="outline-warning">Warning</Button>
</span>
</BackSide>
</React.Fragment>);
const FlippyOnHover = ({ flipDirection = 'vertical' }) => (
<Flippy
flipOnHover={true}
flipDirection={flipDirection}
style={FlippyStyle}
>
<DefaultCardContents>
</DefaultCardContents>
</Flippy>
);
class Flashcard extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
isFlipped: false
}
}
render() {
return (
<div className="App">
<div style={{ display: 'flex', flex: '1 0 200px', justifyContent: 'space-around', 'flex-wrap': 'wrap' }}>
<FlippyOnHover flipDirection="horizontal" />
</div>
</div>
);
}
}
export default Flashcard;
```

THIS IS MY API CALL AND PAGE RENDER

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
import Flashcard from "../components/Flashcard";
import API from "../utils/API";

class Flashcards extends Component {

  state = {
    flashcards: [],
    flashcardName: "",
    flashcardImage: "",
    flipped: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadFlashcards();
  };

  loadFlashcards = () => {
    API.getFlashcards()
      .then(res => {
        // console.log(res.data);
        this.setState({ flashcards: res.data, flashcardName: "", flashcardImage: "" })
        // console.log("flashhhhhhhhhh" + JSON.stringify(this.state.flashcards));
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  flipped = () => {
    console.log(this.state)
    if (this.state.flipped === false) {
      this.setState({ flipped: true })
    }
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.flashcards.length ? (
            <div>
              {this.state.flashcards.map(flashcards => (
                <div key={flashcards._id} >
                  <Flashcard/>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          ) : (
              <h3>No Results to Display</h3>
            )}
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default Flashcards;

Expected result is a dynamically generated array of cards base don API
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your `Flashcard` component to accept props for the title and the URL for the image, assuming that is in the data returned from the API.

In your map, pass the values to the `Flashcard`, something like:

```
{this.state.flashcards.map(flashcard => (
  <div key={flashcard._id}>
    <Flashcard
      title={flashcard.title}
      imageUrl={flashcard.image}
    />
  </div>
))}
```

**Edit:**

Looks like your are using the react-flippy library, so you don't need to manage what state the flash card is in.

Crudly, your `FlashCard` component could look something like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Flippy, { FrontSide, BackSide } from "./../lib";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import "./style.css";
const FlippyStyle = {
  width: "200px",
  height: "200px",
  textAlign: "center",
  color: "#FFF",
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  fontSize: "30px",
  justifyContent: "center"
};

const CardContents = ({ title, imageUrl }) => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <FrontSide
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "white",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
    >
      <img
        src={imageUrl}
        style={{ maxWidth: "100%", maxHeight: "100%" }}
      />
      <span
        style={{
          fontSize: "12px",
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: "10px",
          width: "100%"
        }}
      >
        <br />
        Hover over to show key word
      </span>
    </FrontSide>
    <BackSide
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#EB6864",
        display: "flex",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        flexDirection: "column"
      }}
    >
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <span
        style={{
          fontSize: "12px",
          position: "absolute",
          bottom: "10px",
          width: "100%"
        }}
      >
        <br />
        <Button variant="success">Success</Button>
        <Button variant="outline-warning">Warning</Button>
      </span>
    </BackSide>
  </React.Fragment>
);

class Flashcard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flex: "1 0 200px",
            justifyContent: "space-around",
            "flex-wrap": "wrap"
          }}
        >
          <Flippy flipOnHover={true} flipDirection='horizontal' style={FlippyStyle}>
            <CardContents imageUrl={this.props.imageUrl} title={this.props.title}/>
          </Flippy>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Flashcard;
```

Comment: Thank you! My issue is more on the actual Flashcard component, can you advise how I can modify it so that it accepts these props? Right now it is hard coded withing a const DefaultCardContents that is then used in const FlippyOnHover. Also, to answer your question, the card is being flipped on hover,not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: ~zero2hero Edited

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! I had no idea it could be achieved this way. I really appreciate it!